# Google spreadsheet error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am taking data from a sheet and then converting it to json, so far all good. But when I am trying to take out specific data from arrays but it is making undefined if I get data from array, but when I use raw json data everything works fine

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Users');
  var userData = getUser(ss);
  var array = userData.user.filter(function b(e) { return e.id == 11281 });

  console.log(array)
}

function getUser(ss){
  var usr = {};
  var usrArray = [];

  var data = ss.getRange(2,1,ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++){
    var dataRow = data[i];
    var record = {};

    record['id'] = dataRow[1];
    record['name'] = dataRow[0];
    record['profession'] = dataRow[2];

    usrArray.push(record);
  }
  usr.user = usrArray;
  
  var result = JSON.stringify(usr);
  return result;
}
```

ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMYJ3.png)
[Sheet data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DX1c.png)

If I console log the result directly the it is working fine like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qohtl.png)

Comment: `getUser()` returns a string. A string doesn't have a `user` property.

Comment: Hey @Andreas, thanks for your response. when I console log `result` it shows proper output. I have redited my question to show you the sheet so you can try it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) returns a string — the `getUser` function returns a string. And you're trying to read the `user` property from it which returns `undefined`.

You could do a [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in `doGet` but it's simpler to just return the `usr` object from `getUser`.

```
function getUser(ss) {
  const usr = {}
  const usrArray = []

  // populate usrArray
  usr.user = usrArray
  return usr
}
```

And there's another issue. You're setting `record['id']` to `dataRow[1]` but it should be `dataRow[0]` since `id` is the first column (This is why the shared screenshot has the name in the `id` property). You could also refactor the code.

```
function getUser(ss) {
  const data = ss
    .getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn())
    .getValues()

  const users = data.map((row) => ({
    id: row[0],
    name: row[1],
    profession: row[2],
  }))

  return {
    user: users,
  }
}
```

I would also recommend renaming the `user` property to `users` for clarity.

Comment: Hey @ArunKumarMohan! That was really a great help. That's working perfectly. I wish I could return something to you lol.. I just realized map makes work fast too

Comment: @fhvh No worries!